# Why does Rails use the params variable rather than passing arguments through the function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As title says, why does Rails prefer to use the @params variable inside of a Controller action when you are responding to the action instead of passing the individual parameters through the function arguments when we call the function?

Other frameworks use this (i.e, ASP MVC) and I was just wondering if there was a reason for that design decision, because it doesn't seem very intuitive.

Ie. Why does Rails do

```
def index
    name = params[:name]
end
```

Instead of

```
def index(name)
end
```

Comment: you'd pass all params keys as args in the index method?

Comment: Personally, yeah, it makes the most sense to me (mainly because that's what I'm used to - ASP MVC f.e). The function needs to 'know' about those arguments in order to work, it doesn't make sense to me to "hide" the source of those arguments

Comment: ok so in which orders would you provide them? Or if no order, you'd use a hash? Oh so if you use a hash you've params

Comment: I would provide them in the order they come; or use a hash that's passed through the function. While I can understand what you mean by "Well you already have params", yeah, you're right, however it is clearer to pass it through the method parameters (because you are then saying this method takes these parameters), than to have them auto-magically appear inside the constructor. IMO anyway

Comment: So, in the case of multiple actions, `localhost:3000/products?color=red&quality=best` would appear as `products(color, quality)`. The params hash could be mapped to the name of the parameters, so the order in which the parameters are displayed in the URL doesn't matter. Again this is just my opinion coming from someone who MAINLY uses a statically typed language. It's likely that my opinion doesn't conform to the 'ruby way'.

Comment: understand, just keep in mind that you're in a controller and this class has other methods to let you interact with the stack (params, flash, request, cookies, session etc...). Accessing params is one part of the stack, would you pass session and cookies as args to the index? The controller object is a wrapper of features, like any other object

Comment: I understand that, in case of session/cookies and the like, I would adopt the ASP MVC model and pass the session/cookies into the controller, but the params themselves to the action.

Comment: Also, consider that params passed may greatly differ from a request to an other. This could actually be interesting if methods could be overloaded, like in C++ (several methods having the same name with different parameters) ; but in ruby, it would be more a declaration pain than anything else, and you would probably always end up with something like `def my_action( *params )`

Comment: @DanPantry at some point there will always be "magic". Even if you were to pass the params as method args, you would be hiding the fact that they might have come from either URL parameters (GET) or from the request body (POST). PHP distinguishes these through $_GET and $_POST, for example. So "magic" is a matter of degrees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is, most of the `actions` in a controller handles the view *REST*-fully. The `params` comes from the user's browser when they interact with the page or send a new variable request to the page.
These requests are variable, and Rails makes it uniform by maintaining the parameters in `params` hash. If the following `GET` requests arrive:

```
http://localhost:3000/products?color=red&quality=best
```

the `params` hash will automatically be populated as `{'color' => 'red', 'quality' => 'best'}`. Rails doesn't expect your action to manually handle the parameters.

Similarly, consider you are getting a `POST` request from a page where a user filled a form. In that scenario, the `params` obtain the parameters which are composed with *form helpers* inside views.

Though in hyptothetical case you are dealing with general `methods` instead of `actions`, such as below, **you will** have to do it by passing arguments.

```
def show
  if params['color'] == 'red'
    @product = obtain_product('red')
  else
    #,..
  end
end

def obtain_product(color)
  Product.where('color = ?', color).first
end
```

Hope it is clear. :)

Answer (score 1):

`@kidorrails` has a great answer, and I wanted to add to it:

If you wanted to pass the params to each method directly, it would go against the #1 Rails convention - [keep it DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). By having a separate params hash, you not only have access to *all* the params you want, but you can access them through as many methods as you need

For example, take [`strong_params`](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters):

```
#controller
def new
    @model = Model.new
end

def create
    @model = Model.new(strong_params)
    @model.save
end

private

def strong_params
   params.require(:model).permit(:your, :params)
end
```

As `@apneadiving` mentioned, the params hash is created in another part of the stack, meaning it's available over all the methods required. It's most efficient & versatile way to do it IMO